# Azure DevOps: Error importing Maven artifact from Azure Artifacts into Release

Tags: maven, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

So I'm trying to do a proof of concept with the Azure DevOps stack and a project Java Maven project I usually build with Jenkins and host with Heroku. Initially I was trying to setup a release pipeline straight from the build pipeline WAR file but since it couldn't find it I said to myself "well, if you publish to artifacts it should be straighforward" so I did.

**Build is publishing a maven artifact to Azure Artifacts**

[image: feed]

No issues here as far as I'm concerned. I didn't mess with permissions, but I did notice that under Feed Settings, I cannot selected (it's greyed out) "Allow builds and releases". But the `Project Collection Build Services` is set as a contributor.

**Configuring the artifact in the release**

So here is the first potential issue. The feed shows up in the dropdown but the artifact doesn't. There's only one artifact on the feed so I find this strange:

[image]

So I'm asked to entered it manually and this is where things start to get tricky. To me the id of the artifact should be the maven coordinates `com.acme.demo:reading-time-app`. If I enter that I can proceed, but there's no confirmation that's the right ID:

[image]

**Creating and triggering the release**

So as I create a new release it asks me for the version number and again the dropdown doesn't come up. So I write in version 1.1 which you can confirm from the first screenshot it exists:

[image]

I trigger the release and I get the following error during the `Download Artifact` phase:

```
2019-01-19T17:11:46.7642756Z ##[section]Starting: Download artifact - _com.acme.demoreading-time-app (Azure Artifacts)
2019-01-19T17:11:46.7895376Z ==============================================================================
2019-01-19T17:11:46.7895486Z Task         : Download Package
2019-01-19T17:11:46.7895573Z Description  : Download a package from a Package Management feed in Azure Artifacts or TFS. 
 Requires the Package Management extension.
2019-01-19T17:11:46.7895642Z Version      : 0.1.17
2019-01-19T17:11:46.7895704Z Author       : ms-vscs-rm
2019-01-19T17:11:46.7895757Z Help         : Needs Package Management extension to be installed
2019-01-19T17:11:46.7895859Z ==============================================================================
2019-01-19T17:11:48.2563329Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
2019-01-19T17:11:48.2619024Z ##[error]Failed to get package metadata with error Error: Invalid Resource
2019-01-19T17:11:48.9982590Z ##[section]Finishing: Download artifact - _com.acme.demoreading-time-app (Azure Artifacts)
```

I'm losing my mind here. I'm thinking this should be pretty straighforward but I'm not even at the stage to debug any issues with the deployment into the Azure App Service yet. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: making the id just the artifact name also errors out just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion here - currently, the "Azure Artifacts" artifact type only supports NuGet packages. We should have a string change out in the current deployment making that clearer. We're also working to expand it to support all the other types (Maven, npm, Python, and Universal); that should be available around end of February.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMullians. While you are here, I just went to artifacts because I couldn't add the artifact directly from the maven build. It wouldn't find the WAR in the path. Is there any way to see the state of the filesystem to try and understand why the package isn't found?

Comment: You can browse the last build's output from any step that has a file picker.

It sounds like your build may not have a Publish Build Artifacts step, or if you do, you may be missing a preceding Copy Files step that takes your WAR files from wherever they're built to the folder you've selected to publish in the Publish... step.